# Mac app validation fails due to entitlements issue

Tags: xcode, xcode7, mac-app-store, code-signing-entitlements, app-distribution

I am trying to distribute a version of my Mac app outside the Mac App Store. I have duplicated my target, signed it with "Developer ID", removed iCloud capabilities, created a new entitlements file in which I removed the iCloud and APS entitlements and referenced this in the new target. The target builds and archives just fine, but when I attempt to validate it using "Validate a Developer ID-signed Application", I run into an error:

[image]

Just before the validation step, there is this screen:
[image]

So the app bundle has the correct number of entitlements, but the "A" folders are showing a different number, and do indeed contain the com.apple.developer.aps-environment entitlement. Where is this coming from, why is it different from the app's specified entitlements file, and how do I go about editing it?

---

EDIT: adding target's code-signing settings in Xcode, if that helps:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

have you checked your app before=hand with using :

```
spctl -v -a ./myPath/To/MyApp
```

-v = verbosity
and -a = assess

That will check pretty much most things before presenting it to Apple.

On top of that, have you checked that your signing settings are correct?

Could you post the settings to us so we could see?

Cheers,

A

Comment: What does the spctl command do? When I ran it, it just shows "..path/Contacts Journal copy.app: accepted
override=security disabled"

Comment: spctl deals with the security assessments. If you drop to terminal and pop `man spctl` it'll explain it in some more detail..

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help. It only shows the messageL "MyApp.app: accepted override=security disabled".

Comment: Override security disabled  as far as I know is a a grey area with Apple./ as per your exact error, a little more info would be handy...